# C++20 : Memory allocation of literal initialization of const references

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++20, const-reference, pass-by-const-reference

I am trying to optimize for speed of execution a piece of code using the factory design pattern.

The factory will produce many objects of a class having some members that are constant throughtout the execution of the program, and some members that are not. I **always** initialize the constant members with literals.

**My question is, how is the memory of the constant members going to be managed? Can the compiler optimize the code so that this memory is not allocated/deallocated each time I create/destroy a new object?**

Ideally I would like the literals to reside on a fixed piece of memory and only the reference to this memory be given to each new object. I would like to avoid using global variables.

```
class Test {
private:
  const std::string &name_;
  int value_;
public:
  Test(const std::string &name, int value) : name_(name), value_(value) {}
};

int main() {
  Test test1("A", 1);
  Test test2("B", 2);
  Test test3("B", 3);
  Test test4("A", 4);
  Test test5("B", 5);
  // etc ...
}
```

PS1. notice that in the code snippet the factory pattern implementation is not shown.

PS2. Assume GCC 11.2.0 on Linux

Comment: I think your code has undefined behaviour as it's storing a reference to the temporary `std::string`. Why not just store the `const char*` directly or use `std::string_view` (but not references to `std::string_view` or you'll have the same problem)

Comment: "deally I would like the literals to reside on a fixed piece of memory and only the reference to this memory be given to each new object. I would like to avoid using global variables."  If you have a fixed piece of memory, you might as well name it.

Comment: *Immutable* global data is unproblematic. It's not the scope that is the problem with globals, it's the shared mutable state. If you're literally concerned about the scope, use a namespace.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for pointing out that possibility. However, assuming my understanding is correct, it seems that [it is an official C++ feature to extend the lifetime of a temporary object to the lifetime of the const reference which refers to it](https://blog.galowicz.de/2016/03/23/const_reference_to_temporary_object/).

Comment: In your link see `Please note that this does not apply to const reference class members, only to local const references!`. That's why I said `I think`, the rules on const reference life extension are complex so I find it simpler to just avoid it

Comment: @AlanBirtles Apparently my understanding was not correct after all!

Comment: Note that you likely have small string optimization in your STL so "A" does not allocate heap space and copy "A" into it but copies "A" directly into the `std::string` object. What you can do is use `const char *` so the literals can be referenced, make your constructor constexpr and constinit all your Test objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is just to make `name_` a `const char *`:

```
class Test {
private:
  const char *const name_;
  int value_;
public:
  Test(const char *name, int value) : name_(name), value_(value) {}
};

int main() {
  Test test1("A", 1);
  Test test2("B", 2);
  Test test3("B", 3);
  Test test4("A", 4);
  Test test5("B", 5);
  // etc ...
}
```

That works because the compiler will optimize strings in memory, so that in this case you don't need multiple copies of `"A"` in memory.

Unfortunately, the code you supply will not work, and leaves a dangling reference.  The reason is that the [rules for when to extend temporary object lifetimes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.temporary#6) extend when the reference is bound to a temporary materialization of an object.  However, in your code, the temporary `std::string` is first bound to `name`, and then `name` is bound to `name_`.  So the temporarily materialized `std::string` will be destroyed at the semicolon.

One downside to using a `const char *` is that you will lose length information in the event that you want to embed NUL characters (`'\0'`) in your string.  A potential work around would be to take the length of the string as a template argument, as in:

```
class Test {
private:
  const char *const name_;
  const std::size_t size_;
  int value_;
public:
  template<std::size_t N>
  Test(const char name[N], int value)
    : name_(name), size_(N-1), value_(value) {}
};
```

Comment: Perhaps use `string_view`.

Comment: Using a `string_view` seems kind of error-prone, in case someone passes in a `std::string`.  Maybe if the constructor is `consteval`?